# Two interface with same method name

Tags: c#, .net

Is it ok to have one implementation for a method with the same name from two interfaces?

I was convinced that we need always do explicity implement `IFoo1.Bar()`, but the code below is compiling and running. Any thoughts?

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    interface IFoo1
    {
        void Bar();
    }
    interface IFoo2
    {
        void Bar();
    }
    class Foo : IFoo1, IFoo2
    {
        public void Bar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.Bar();

            IFoo1 iFoo1 = new Foo();
            iFoo1.Bar();

            IFoo2 iFoo2 = new Foo();
            iFoo2.Bar();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works if both interfaces can share the same implementation.

Comment: Many people including the interviewers have this misconception, explicit implementation means to allow the interface only to access the method not even `this` can access that method without type casting.